# Apply an authentication filter in a Spring REST API depending on the method called

Tags: java, spring, rest, authentication

We have a REST API built on Spring boot, with some public methods and some private methods.

We implemented an `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` to handle a JWT authentication, and everything works fine.

However, we would like to apply this filter only on the private methods, as the public ones do not need any authentication done. Problem is the urls can't be used to separate public and private methods (i.e. /account/get/{id} is public, but /account/personal/{id} is private, with no common pattern between all private or all public urls).

It seems the `HttpSecurity` only allows us to use the urls to apply filters, when we would prefer to apply the authentication filter only when a method with `@PreAuthorize` is called.

The only way we imagine for doing it is to use reflections and, during the web security configuration, discover at runtime all methods with `@PreAuthorize`, find back their urls, and use those to build a RequestMatcher listing all their precise endpoints.

Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: I am just curious, but how many such "public" method does your API has? Normally, I'd say "pre-authorize all, then manually exclude by url patterns those you don't want to have authorized". in this case, if something will be forgotten, you will quickly notice it while testing.

Comment: Could be a lot, the API will be used to provide data to a website with public information. If it is really needed, we will split the API in /api/public/ and /api/private/, but if we can avoid it it will be nice.

Comment: I would say, that would a good idea to begin with, even it's not a lot, because probably those API have different use-cases and different audiences, so from the good system design point of view they should be kept separate..

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me, I guess you want to access private APIs with JWT and Public APIs without JWT. if so, just mention the API path in Websurity to ignore JWT authentication.

Below code for manually update the API which does not sequence.

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/url1", "/api/url2")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/url3");
    }
```

Other than APIs which are mentioned in WebSecurity ignoring, will be an authorized access

Below code for the APIs which starts with `/api/public`

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/api/public/**");
    }
```

Comment: I think OP has emphasized that they don't want to exclude URLs manually

Comment: I have added extra code to ignore security to all the APIs which starts with `/api/public`